# How to set center point of marker icon as the target position?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Recently I am using google map api v3 to develop a program. I met a problem. The icon of the marker I am using is a circle icon, just as following:

[image]

We know when we place a marker on google map, the latitude and longitude will be placed below the icon. Now I want to use the center point of the circle icon as the target place, How to realize that?

```
var result_marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
    position: result_latlng, 
    map: map, 
    icon: result_icon 
});
```

Comment: What code are you using to set the position of the marker?

Comment: very simple, just like:`code`var result_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: result_latlng,
       map: map,
       icon: result_icon
      });`code`

Comment: What is the size of the `result_icon`?